# Overloading comparator of priority queue in Python

Tags: python, queue

Guys in C to push nodes into a priority queue we had to overload the < operator . Is there anything similar to that in python priority queue.

e.g in C :

```
    struct node
    {

    int city , weight

    }

    bool operator < (node a, node b)
    {
     return a.weight > b.weight;
    }

    int main()
   {
     node a,b,c;
     priority_queue <node> pq;
     pq.push(a);pq.push(b);pq.push(c);
     return 0;
   }
```

Is there any analogous way to define priority queue in Python ; if so help needed , I could not make to head or tail of the python.org docs for priority queue . I saw a couple of explanation on stackoverflow , a bit of more explanation is needed . Thanks.

Comment: Did you even try to google this?

Comment: This is not C , and I think I asked a valid question; there was no necessity in down-voting me .

Answer (score 8):

Wrap the data in a class and override `__cmp__` to return what you'd like for your comparison.  E.g.

```
class PQEntry:

    def __init__(self, priority, value):
        self.priority = priority
        self.value = value

    def __cmp__(self, other):
         return cmp(self.priority, other.priority)
```

Comment: I think you meant to compare by priority? Otherwise the example wouldn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @NiklasB. you're right, it seems someone has already made the edit, though

Comment: Yes, that was me ;) Just wanted to make you aware of it in case I misunderstood your post.